# Access Graylog Docker container on url subpath

Tags: nginx, docker, graylog2

I tried to access graylog on a subpath. For example like myapp.com/graylog. I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy to pass a request to `/graylog` to my `graylog` instance. The graylog instance is setup using the official [graylog docker image](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-images/tree/master/docker).

My location in the NGINX config:

```
 location /graylog {
      # TODO this does not work currently as graylog has no option to run on a subpath (assets are served from root)
     # Option 1: Find the option to run graylog on a subpath
     # Option 2: Run graylog on a sub sub domain
     rewrite ^/graylog/?(.*) /$1 break;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass http://myip:9000;
     proxy_read_timeout 90;
     proxy_redirect / /graylog/;
 }
```

I assume that we have to tell graylog somehow that it runs on a subpath. Anybody an idea how to achieve that?

Also opened an [issue](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-images/issues/98) at the graylog docker repo.